# default Guess Component Route is not showing anything

Tags: angular

I am making a app where default router is **login component** and from login component when user click on related path it go further.

My **app.module.ts** file look like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GuessComponent } from './guess/guess.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GuessComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: "/login",
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      { path: 'login', component: GuessComponent },

      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my **app.component.html**

What is wrong in my code, because when i **run app** it doesn't show anything.

Comment: did you get any error in your console?

Comment: Share complete app.module code

Comment: there is no error

Comment: try putting your redirect route as the last item of the array, and replace the pathMatch value with `prefix`

Comment: i have added my complete app.moudle.ts in question

Comment: Try adding entryComponents: [AppComponent] after providers.

Comment: Did you add <base href="/"> in index.html

Comment: yeah it works now

Comment: If that works, upvote  the comment so that others can make use of it.